# Adding column names to vars() inside a dplyr function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that can be used for summarizing a variable based on some user-defined groups, making use of `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

get_var_summary <- function(.data, .target_var, .group_vars = vars()) {
  .target_var = enquo(.target_var)
  return(
    .data %>%
      filter(!is.na(!! .target_var)) %>% 
      group_by_at(.vars = .group_vars) %>% 
      summarize(
        mean = mean(!! .target_var),
        sd = sd(!! .target_var),
        ci = qnorm(0.975) * sd(!! .target_var) / sqrt(n()),
        median = median(!! .target_var),
        n = n()
      ) %>% 
      mutate(
        sd = ifelse(is.na(sd), Inf, sd),
        ci = ifelse(is.na(ci), Inf, ci)
      ) %>% 
      ungroup()
  )
}

mtcars %>% 
  get_var_summary(wt, .group_vars = vars(cyl))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
    cyl  mean    sd    ci median     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1    4.  2.29 0.570 0.337   2.20    11
2    6.  3.12 0.356 0.264   3.22     7
3    8.  4.00 0.759 0.398   3.76    14
```

Now, in order to be able to easily repeat the `.group_vars`, but occasionally supply another grouping var in addition, I would like to define another function that calls `get_var_summary`, but with one additional column added to `.group_vars`:

```
get_var_summary_by_another <- function(.data, .extra_var, .target_var, .group_vars = vars()) {

  # how do I add .extra_var to .group_vars?

}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create one function to accomplish your goal of using an arbitrary number of grouping variables to summarize on. You can rewrite the original function using a combination of `dplyr::group_by()`, `dplyr::across()`, and [curly curly embracing](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions) `{{`. This works with dplyr version 1.0.0 and greater.

I've edited the original example and code for clarity.

```r
library(tidyverse)

var_summary <- function(.data, target, group = NULL) {
  .data %>%
    filter(!is.na({{ target }})) %>% 
    group_by(across({{ group }})) %>% 
    summarize(
      "mean_{{target}}" := mean({{ target }}),
      sd := sd({{ target }}),
      ci := qnorm(0.975) * sd({{ target }}) / sqrt(n()),
      "median_{{target}}" := median({{ target }}),
      "n_{{target}}" := n()
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
      sd := if_else(is.na(sd), Inf, sd),
      ci := if_else(is.na(ci), Inf, ci)
    ) %>%
    rename("sd_{{target}}" := sd, "ci_{{target}}" := ci)
}

var_summary(mtcars, target = wt)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   mean_wt sd_wt ci_wt median_wt  n_wt
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1    3.22 0.978 0.339      3.32    32

var_summary(mtcars, target = wt, group = cyl)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>     cyl mean_wt sd_wt ci_wt median_wt  n_wt
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4    2.29 0.570 0.337      2.2     11
#> 2     6    3.12 0.356 0.264      3.22     7
#> 3     8    4.00 0.759 0.398      3.76    14

var_summary(mtcars, target = wt, group = c(cyl, gear))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 8 x 7
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  gear mean_wt   sd_wt   ci_wt median_wt  n_wt
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4     3    2.46 Inf     Inf          2.46     1
#> 2     4     4    2.38   0.601   0.416      2.26     8
#> 3     4     5    1.83   0.443   0.614      1.83     2
#> 4     6     3    3.34   0.173   0.240      3.34     2
#> 5     6     4    3.09   0.413   0.405      3.16     4
#> 6     6     5    2.77 Inf     Inf          2.77     1
#> 7     8     3    4.10   0.768   0.435      3.81    12
#> 8     8     5    3.37   0.283   0.392      3.37     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to first splice the `.group_vars` with `!!!`, and add the `.extra_var` to a new `vars()` call:

```
get_var_summary_by_another <- function(.data, .extra_var, .target_var, .group_vars = vars()) {
  .extra_var = enquo(.extra_var)
  .target_var = enquo(.target_var)
  .group_vars = vars(!!! .group_vars, !! .extra_var)
  return(
    .data %>% get_var_summary(
      !! .target_var,
      .group_vars
    )
  )
}

mtcars %>% 
get_var_summary_by_another(gear, .target_var = wt, .group_vars = vars(cyl))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
    cyl  gear  mean      sd      ci median     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1    4.    3.  2.46 Inf     Inf       2.46     1
2    4.    4.  2.38   0.601   0.416   2.26     8
3    4.    5.  1.83   0.443   0.614   1.83     2
4    6.    3.  3.34   0.173   0.240   3.34     2
5    6.    4.  3.09   0.413   0.405   3.16     4
6    6.    5.  2.77 Inf     Inf       2.77     1
7    8.    3.  4.10   0.768   0.435   3.81    12
8    8.    5.  3.37   0.283   0.392   3.37     2
```